# Is the below code correct to save the bytes to file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to save the byte array to a file. File contents are not being saved to that file.

```
HttpWebRequest lxRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("imageurl");
String lsResponse = string.Empty;
using (HttpWebResponse lxResponse = (HttpWebResponse)lxRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(lxResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Byte[] lnByte = reader.ReadBytes(1 * 1024 * 1024 * 10);
        String path = Application.StartupPath + "\\abc.jpg";
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, lnByte);
    }
}
```

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: do you get any error or abc.jpg is simply empty?

Comment: no error is coming. also file contents are not being saved in this file.

Comment: how about tracing to see if the lnByte has any value?

Comment: try imageurl w/o quotas in WebRequest.Create(imageurl)

Comment: _file contents are not being saved in this file_ ... but is a file created?  (e.g., empty)

Comment: yes file is being created.

Comment: @Afshin : File contents are present and WebRequest is sending the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (Stream response = lxResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    response.CopyTo(fs);
}
```